# How to manually install libgeos library for use with Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to run some Python code that says it requires the libgeos binary library to support Python shapely libraries. I believe I found a github file for libgeos here:
https://github.com/OSGeo/geos

I cannot download this using pip because I think it's a C++ file. How do I install this package manually? I am using Windows 10 and all I currently have installed is Python 2.7 and Anaconda. I am new to Python so I am not sure if I am using the correct terms.